# How to go from PayPal permissions API Access Token to executing GetExpressCheckout

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-permissions

Using Angeleyes excellent Permissions tutorial and code, I have managed a small developer site, that can get Access Token and Token Secret. From there Im clueless, Paypals' Github claims a CreateInvoice sample, which doesnt exsist, and much searching i have learned(?).

You need to include your app credentials, your `API` username and `API` password, and in an added `"SUBJECT"` line the `... payer_ID merchant/payer email...` 
(conflicting info exsists here) to run another `API` you have permission to execute.

None of this is very clear for me. All tutorials end with the access code and Token secret.

I am attempting to add a buy now button that sources the `MERCHANT` from DB (multi merchant) but am getting nowhere overcoming this conceptual gap.

How do i mesh Permissions `API` with `ExpressCheckout API`? (step by step if possible)

Edit:

Search continues also, how does one recover  from the permissions granting api methord the merchant email for subject?!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal updated their description DURING the grant permissions screen, to mention Pal Id access..

Now going to open a new question, to find out how to use a saved Permissions Token and Secret in php to USE the access token and token secret to get pal ID.

hope this helps someone else :)